# mod_rewrite not working - results in 404 error and no logs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’m running localhost XAMPP on my Mac and trying to setup the Apache server with mod_rewrite, here’s my code in `.htaccess` (which is in htdocs)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On                                        # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteRule ^test/?$ api/rest/v1.0/api_controller.php?request=$1 [NOCASE,LAST]      # Handle requests for “test"

    RewriteLog "logs/rewritelog"
    RewriteLogLevel 7

</IfModule>
```

This is the only code in the `.htaccess` file too.

When I try my link `http://localhost/test/1` in my browser, I just get directed to a 404 error.

I’ve checked under htdocs/logs/rewritelog but there aren’t any files nor even a folder called logs.

**UPDATE**

I’m running Apache version 2.4.10

Comment: You don't have a rewrite rule matching `/test/1`. Maybe try `^test/(.*)$`

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck

Comment: Any thoughts on why there are no logs?

Comment: There are no rewrite logs because your URL `/test/1` is not matching any rewrite rules.

Comment: I tried corrupting the file by renaming ‘IfModule’ to ‘le’ and the same error occurred. I think my server is ignoring the `.htaccess` file

Comment: Any ideas why the server might ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the .htaccess file was saved as .htaccess.txt where the .txt extension was hidden. If you get the same error, check the file in Get Info.